# woocommerce subscriptions - get expiration date

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

Using the call back hook, I can get the subscription information of everything EXCEPT the expiration date.  Any thoughts on how to grab this.  This is what I have:

```
function mmd_woointerface_ProcessOrder($order_id) 
{
$order           = new WC_Order( $order_id );                  
$OrderNumber     = $order->parent_id;
$ParentOrder     = new WC_Order( $OrderNumber );
$TransactionId   = $ParentOrder->get_transaction_id();

$DatePaid                   = $order->date_created;
$SubscriptionNumber         = $order->get_order_number();
$PaymentDate                = $order->get_date_created()->format ('Y-m-d');
$ProductId                  = $product->get_product_id();  
$subscriptions              = wcs_get_users_subscriptions( $UserId );
foreach ($subscriptions as $sub)
  {
  if($sub->ID == $SubscriptionNumber)                              
  $ExpireDate = $sub->get_expiration_date( 'next_payment' ); <<NOT ACCURATE
  $ExpireDate = WC_Subscriptions_Order::get_next_payment_date ( $ParentOrder, $ProductId  );   << SAME PROBLEM
  }
 }
```

These calls:

```
 $ExpireDate = $sub->get_expiration_date( 'next_payment' ); 

 $ExpireDate = WC_Subscriptions_Order::get_next_payment_date ( $ParentOrder, $ProductId  );
```

are not effective when you have a user who makes a manual early payment. It just returns the next payment date, verses the actual stored expiration date

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to the one you have described. In the end i had to hook into `woocommerce_subscription_status_active` from which you can access the related `$subscription` object as a single argument. If you need any further details from the standard `$order` object also then you can access that via `$subscription->get_parent()` within your function.

The issue seems to be that the end date value attached to a subscription only gets set really late in the order of hooks/actions, so any of the standard hooks you would usually use post-checkout may not have access to the subscription dates yet since they are still not set.

I tried all of the following before i got it to work for me;

```
woocommerce_thankyou
woocommerce_payment_complete
woocommerce_checkout_order_processed
woocommerce_order_status_completed
woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete
```

and in each case the end date (and next payment date) were both empty even though i could see them in the wordpress admin later on.

Comment: thank you.  I did find the solution and yes it used the payment complete method.

Comment: which "payment complete" method? the ones listed in my answer are all the ones which **dont** work. it was only ```woocommerce_subscription_status_active``` which worked for me

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete', 'woointerface_PaymentComplete_call', 1, 2);  

Works super.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation ([product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/product-functions/#section-17), [subscription](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/#section-3)) I would assume that either

```
WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_expiration_date( $ProductId );
```

or

```
WC_Subscription::get_date( 'end' );
```

should return the expiration date.

Comment: That does not work and have done that, since it is the product line and just does a calculation based on today's date.  'end' is used when a subscription type has a end, these subscriptions never "end", they just renew.   But somewhere the new date is stored.